# How do you vet DNA cousin "matches" that reach out to you?

Tags: dna, communication

I did the DNA test thing back in January.  One of the things I was hoping to get out of it was to make contact with other (distant) cousins. What I didn't think about was putting myself out there for spearphishers.  We put a lot of personal facts out there that could be used to harvest Personally Identifiable Information.

Do you have any safeguards or tips for when you get a potential cousin that reaches out to you (i.e. only those with a certain length of shared DNA)?  I've started this process being super trusting, but the more I talk to people, the more my cyber-security training starts to kick in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite willing to talk about my great-grandparents (say) to people that I appear to be related to.  They've all been dead for 50+ years (or more).

Talking about my wife and kids, on the other hand, not so much.

How do I vet them?
I look at my research; I look at their trees and try to find records to confirm the (claimed) relationship.

Comment: I have some recent voids in my tree.  It's not always possible to place em.  I have one I'm talking to now that seems more willing to hear about my family then share the tree of theirs.  When they finally did, it was a link to a private tree on Ancestry with no invitation to that tree.  I don't know if it's a lack of understanding how these sites work or someone playing confused.  (And feel like garbage for doubting them if authentic)

Comment: I'm not saying "don't be wary" - in your shoes I might be wary, too.

It's more "I don't see any PII issues when discussing people who were born in 1890"